# Why is there no feminine version of "der Fahrgast"?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

Given that passengers can be both men and women, I was expecting to find something like "die Fahrgastin" in the dictionary, but I can't find it.

Is there a reason for this, or is it simply an exception?

Comment: The same is true for "der Gast", of course. You may wish to edit your question to cover the more general case.

Comment: Grammatical genders do not refer to the gender of the object they describe. They are just an order given to words. Only recently professions like "Bäcker" or "Lehrer" have been "genderized" in both male and female versions because it was assumed women feel more acknowledged for their work then. But of course, this doesn't apply to non-jobs as "Gast".

Comment: Have a look at http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gaestin. Actually nobody uses that word, but probably you could transfer it to "Fahrgast". @Janka Gast is also "genderized".

Comment: @Janka I understand that grammatical genders do not, in general, refer to the gender of the object they describe. But most of the time, when it comes to people, they do. And not just for professionals. For example, der Freund and die Freundin, der Vater and die Mutter, der Kollegen and die Kollegin, and der Patient and die Patientin.

Comment: @JosephDieudonné: Wenn Du das Geschlecht betonen willst, sagst Du "männlicher Fahrgast" oder "weiblicher Fahrgast", so wie auch "Kollege, Patient" alleine keinen Mann bezeichnen, sondern eine Person, die mit einer anderen zusammenarbeitet bzw. von einer anderen geheilt werden kann, und wie "Person" auch kein Geschlecht hat und nicht gegendert werden kann, wie auch "Mitglied", "Flüchtling", "Fachkraft/Hilfskraft" oder "Koryphäe". Bei Freund/Freundin kann man wohl zu selten vom Geschlecht absehen, aber eine Zusammensetzung wie  "Brieffreund" lässt auch das Geschlecht offen.

Comment: @TeXnician: "Gästin" ist eine Veräpplung des Gendersprechs und geht m.W. auf Gerburg Jahnke (Ladies Night, Missfitts) zurück. Als ernsthafte Sprachform kann man das niemandem empfehlen.

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht. Kann man ein weiblicher Patient sein? Ich dachte "eine Patientin" richtig sein.

Comment: @JosephDieudonné both are fine. I personally would say "Patientin", unless I want to emphasize the sex. "Weiblicher Patient" is basically "adjective describing biological gender" + "generic (often identical to male) term". A made-up counter-example would be "männliche Hebamme", but that doesn't really exist, the word "Geburtshelfer" was introduced as male (+generic) term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a *rule of thumb*, you are correct:

*Most* jobs or roles for people have a form denoting (biological) male or female individuals. Sometimes there are completely different words, e.g. **Vater** and **Mutter**, sometimes the female gets an "-in" attached (and sometimes an umlaut), e.g. **Koch**/**Köchin**. Typically, the male form is also the generic, gender-neutral form.

But yes, there are exceptions and with your "(Fahr)Gast", you found one of them.
And they come in all (gramatical) genders: Der **Gast**, das **Opfer**, die **Leiche**.
In all those cases, you depend on either context or a clarifying adjective to determine the biological gender.

Comment: Das ist falsch. Typisch ist vielmehr, dass es eine generische Form gibt wie "der Koch, der Brite, der Student", die eben nichts über das Geschlecht der Person aussagt. Die Form kann nicht generisch und für Männer exklusiv zugleich sein und ist es auch nicht. Wenn mit Student, Brite oder Koch nur männliche Personen gemeint sein sollen muss sich das entweder aus dem Kontext ergeben ("Peter ist Brite"), ergibt sich also nicht aus dem Wort oder es muss ausdrücklich dazugesagt werden ("männliche Studenten dürfen am Seminar nicht teilnehmen").